# JQuery action scrolls window down

Tags: jquery, scroll, window

I'm running this JQuery script to scroll divs

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/rs2QK/

```
jQuery(function($) {

        $('a.panel').click(function() {
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $other = $target.siblings('.active');

            if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
                $other.each(function(index, self) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                        left: $this.width()
                    }, 500);
                });

                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            }
        });

    });
```

Problem is if for example, there is a header above this two divs which has some height, JQuery will scroll window down for that same headers height on action.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **return false** at bottom ,when binding event to anchor element.It will prevent adding # in url and your issues.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.panel').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```